# html2canvas rendring path and line

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to create a 'screenshot' of a HTML page that contain a map page. The problem  is the rendering of polyline option from leaflet libarary to canvas. when use polyline in leaflet to draw a line on the map and take screen shot by html2canvas library, then the line does not appear.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see google map api v3 visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=es

Comment: thank you from your response but my problem is some thing else. I have exported the map from shape files by the help of tilemill application and now, is being implemented on my website using leaflet library. When using leaflet polyline option then html2canvas cant support the polyline option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed `L_PREFER_CANVAS = true` prior to the Leaflet include?
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-canvas

Comment: When make "L_PREFER_CANVAS = true" then the polyline does not work and does not display the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is done. make "L_PREFER_CANVAS=true and L_DIABLE_3D=true prior to the leaflet include.